# how to display reserved cinema seats again in c programming

Tags: c

The following is the code I made for a seat reservation at the cinema. the problem is when I display seats again after reservation it's not displaying the reserved seats.
p.s: I can see the message "seat is already reserved but it is not displaying on the screen.

0=empty seats.

1=reserved seats.

THIS IS CODING:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void DisplaySeats(void);
void ReserveSeats(void);
void ChooseSeat(void);
int Seats[4][10];
int main()
{
printf("Welcome to our small Cinema!!!\n");
printf("\n");
DisplaySeats();
ReserveSeats();

printf("Thankyou for Choosing our small Cinema !! \n");

getch();
}
void ChooseSeat(void)
{

 int row, col,k;
 printf("Which row do you want to choose? : ");
scanf_s("%d", &row);
printf("Which seat do you want to select? : ");
scanf_s("%d", &col);
if (row > 4 || col > 10)
{
    printf("Wrong Entry !! Try again\n");
    ChooseSeat();
 }
 else if (Seats[row - 1][col - 1] != 0)
 {
    printf("Seat is already reserved try again !!\n");
    ChooseSeat();
 }
 else
 {
    Seats[row - 1][col - 1] = 1;
    printf("Congratulations!! Reservation Completed!!!\n");
    DisplaySeats();
 }


}

void ReserveSeats(void)
{
 int NoOfSeats,i;
 printf("How many seats do you want to reserve?\n");
 scanf_s("%d", &NoOfSeats);
 for (i = 1; i <= NoOfSeats; i++)
 {
    ChooseSeat();
 }


}
void DisplaySeats(void)
{
 int i, j;
 int Seats[4][10] = { 0 };
 printf("\t \t Seats\n");
 printf("\t1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10\n");

 for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
 {
    printf("Rows %d: ", i + 1);
    for (j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        printf("%d ", Seats[i][j]);
    printf("\n");
  }
 printf("\n");

 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your `DisplaySeats` function. You have a local `Seats[4][10]` in your display function, which means your global variable `Seats[4][10]` will be hidden inside your `DisplaySeats`.

Every time you call `DisplaySeats`, you just show a brand new `Seats`, **NOT** the one you modified in your `ChooseSeat` function. So just get rid of `int Seats[4][10] = { 0 };` in your `DisplaySeats` function , and you'll be fine.

Comment: so i should use **int Seats[4][10] = { 0 };** as global variable ?

Comment: @Muneer yes, you can do that. Just delete int Seats[4][10] = { 0 }; in your display function and you'll get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I solved some years ago the same problem with the following idea:
each row of the cinema is a linked list and each element of the list contain an address of a new linked list for each column.

For the persistence of the information use file.txt
You can see it in my repository on github:
https://github.com/LombardoAndrea195/Sistemi_Operativi_Project/tree/master/Sistemi_Operativi_Lombardo